# Service-Worker Warning in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send web notifications.
i am getting this warning and clicking the notifications does not give the usual result (open the notification url). this is the Service-Worker code

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
'messagingSenderId': '<my senderid>'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {


  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }).then(function() {
      return clients.openWindow(payload.data.locator);
    });

    event.waitUntil(promise);
  });

  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

```
firebase-messaging-sw.js:108 Event handler of 'notificationclick' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.
```

this is the warning message, 108 reffers to this line

`self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {`

this is on chrome version 55.
on firefox, nothing is wrong and it runs perfectly normal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: to be more specific, it does open the expected url, but just the first notification in each instance of chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You should move**

```
self.addEventListener
```

outside the function

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler
```

So that you add the EventListener only once.

**Your full code should look like**

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }).then(function() {
      return clients.openWindow(event.data.locator);
    });

    event.waitUntil(promise);
  });

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {   

  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    locator:payload.data.locator
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: I did this way, but the click just never work at all

Answer (score 3):

Use **self.addEventListener** outside of **messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler**
and use **data** property of **notificationOptions**

below is complete ***firebase-messaging-sw.js*** file for better understanding

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-messaging.js');

 // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apkiiiiiiiKeyyyyyy",
    authDomain: "authhhhhhDomaiiiiinnnnn",
    databaseURL: "urlllllll",
    projectId: "projjjjIIIDDDD",
    storageBucket: "buuuuuuuu",
    messagingSenderId: "111111111111"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 500);
    }).then(function() {
      return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data);
    });
    event.waitUntil(promise);
  });


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
    image: payload.data.image,
    data: payload.data.link,
    tag: "bg"
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
```

as simple as that